# iOS: Set setImageInputs of image slideshow to array of images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image

I'm using an image slideshow from [here](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow):

```
    iconArr = [UIImage(named: "home-min")!,UIImage(named: "category-
   min")!,UIImage(named: "settings-min")!,UIImage(named: "contact us-min")!,UIImage(named: "about us-min")!,UIImage(named: "logout")!]
```

I need to make this array as an image source.

```
for image in self.iconArr {
            let img = image
            self.SlideShow.setImageInputs([ImageSource(image:  img)])
             }
```

But that is not working, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should try this way for sure, because you reset inputs in your `for-loop`

```
var imageSource: [ImageSource] = []
for image in self.iconArr {
    let img = image
    imageSource.append(ImageSource(image:  img))
}
self.SlideShow.setImageInputs(imageSource)
```

As sooper stated, can be done this way

```
let imageSources = self.iconArr.map { ImageSource(image: $0) }
```

Comment: Many Thanx.
It's Works.

Comment: @AliJalil accept then please, might help someone in future. Happy to be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I do that.

Comment: The mapping can be done in one line as well: `let imageSources = self.iconArr.map { ImageSource(image: $0) }`

Comment: can it be possible with SDWebImageSouce?

Comment: @neha why not? sure

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution from this url [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461970/5628693][1]

Below is my code working fine :

```
 var imageSDWebImageSrc = [SDWebImageSource]()
@IBOutlet weak var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!
```

Add below viewDidLoad()

```
 slideshow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    slideshow.slideshowInterval = 5.0
    slideshow.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.underScrollView
    slideshow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    slideshow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    slideshow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    // optional way to show activity indicator during image load (skipping the line will show no activity indicator)
    slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
    slideshow.currentPageChanged = {
        page in
        print("current page:", page)
    }

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Dashboard.didTap))
    slideshow.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
} // now add below func 
@objc func didTap() {
    let fullScreenController = slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)
    // set the activity indicator for full screen controller (skipping the line will show no activity indicator)
    fullScreenController.slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator(style: .white, color: nil)
}
```

And last step i was getting json data from below alamofire request

```
  Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
   if(response.value == nil){
        }
   else {
        let json2 = JSON(response.value!)
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()

            if let details = json2["imgs"].array {
                for dItem in details {

                   let  img = dItem["img"].stringValue

                   let image = SDWebImageSource(urlString: self.imgurl+img)
                    self.imageSDWebImageSrc.append(image!)
                }
             self.slideshow.setImageInputs(self.imageSDWebImageSrc)
            }
            break
        case .failure( _):

            break

        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks dude :) happy coding