# How to pass image value to the ImageSlideshow using Swift

Tags: swift, slideshow, sdwebimage

I am trying to get images into the ImageSlideshow with SDWebImage. I can get the images but can't format them. I hope I am making sense.

```
let url="https://myoscapp.com/boot/json_procuct_info.php"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
          let json = JSON(value)               
          let   imageslider=json[0]["products_gallery"].array
          if json[0]["products_gallery"].array != nil {
               let imageQuantity=imageslider?.count

               var i = 0
                    while i < imageQuantity! {

            let individualimage=imageslider?[i]["image"].stringValue


                        print(individualimageUrl!)
                        i=i+1
                    }


            }
```

Comment: The url is invalid. Please add an url which can work or show where did you got problem

Comment: Please be more concise and precise what exactly is not working with the relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let try this to add `SDWebImage` to `ImageSlideshow`

**Create outlet for your slideshow**

> `@IBOutlet var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!`

With your ***Example*** :

```
var imageSDWebImageSrc = [SDWebImageSource]()

let url="https://myoscapp.com/boot/json_procuct_info.php"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
          let json = JSON(value)               
          let   imageslider = json[0]["products_gallery"].array
          if json[0]["products_gallery"].array != nil {
               for url in imageslider{
                   let image = SDWebImageSource(urlString: url)
                   if let sdURL = image{
                     imageSDWebImageSrc.append(sdURL)
                   }
               }
              self.slideshow.setImageInputs(self.imageSDWebImageSrc)
          }
        }
    }
```

**in Addition:**

[How to set ImageSlideshow image sources for ImageSource, SDWebImage, AFURLSource, AlamofireSource, KingfisherSource.](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow/blob/master/Example/ImageSlideshow/ViewController.swift)

**Update:**
You have to install it.

```
pod "ImageSlideshow/SDWebImage"
```

Run `pod install`

Comment: if let details = json2["imgs"].array {
                    for dItem in details {

                       let  img = dItem["img"].stringValue
                   
                        self.logoImages.append(self.imgurl+img) // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'SDWebImageSource'
                        imageSDWebImageSrc.append(self.imgurl+img)
                    }
                 self.slideshow.setImageInputs(self.imageSDWebImageSrc)
                }

Comment: have to add this line. check answer again let image = SDWebImageSource(urlString: url)

Comment: Showing error in this line : imageSDWebImageSrc.append(self.imgurl+img) // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'SDWebImageSource'